# High kernel usage in Windows 10 (after upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, performance, windows-10-upgrade

### TL;DR;

There are high kernel usages all the time (I have other Win10 installations I could compare it to) and I've tried to do as much of my own investigation as possible (screens included).

At... beginning of this year, I finally upgraded to Win10 (given all the support from apps and games steadily vanishing in older OSes). After booting up, the system felt just as quick and capable with few exceptions here and there.

One exception was that my "f.lux" (a blue-light blocking app that has the orange filter during the night) stopped working. I also noticed that whenever moving a window (any), its process would spike in Task Manager as per CPU usage. This I tracked down to Devices Manager where the monitor driver that Windows was using was not from Microsoft or DELL (my monitor vendor), but rather the TeamViewer driver (which is normally used only during remote sessions I guess). I completely uninstalled TeamViewer, then GPU drivers in safe mode with DDU, and did a clean install. All seemed fine but then I discovered the major problem underneath.

Whenever the system was running for a prolonged time (since login/session started) it would feel whole sluggish. After restart or just logout/login it would again run "fine" (just apparently). By "fine" and "sluggish", I mean that when I move the windows around they move at refresh rate and not lower (for example 5-15 fps - just my approximation). The CPU usage when moving the windows I mentioned before, is still ever-present.

I started to try out games and stuff and noticed that my overall rig performance (or FPS in games) could go as low as half as before (in Windows 7). Then I found it. KERNEL USAGE!

Kernel time vs User time in Process Explorer

[image: Kernel time vs User time in Process Explorer]

It was only logical that CPU usages of processes combined would or COULD not stack up to overall:

Task Manager process usage does not stack

[image: Task Manager process usage does not stack]

(sometimes they do though, I attribute this to Task Manager being confused by CPU usage that is apparently directly from processes, or I just don't understand jack sh*t how Task Manager and kernel-time work).

Anyways, I started to fool around with apps like LatencyMon and WhySoSlow, and sometimes it would show DPC routines, sometimes ISR routines, and sometimes both:

High ISR routine time - after very long uptime

[image: High ISR routine time - after very long uptime]

High DPC routine & interrupt to latency times

[image: High DPC routine & interrupt to latency times]

I've also managed to capture a screen where WhySoSlow reports critical times of responsiveness of kernel:

[image: Critical kernel responsiveness time]

Here is a screen of execution times of routines of drivers directly but I've not been able to tell by that solely if there is some faulty driver:

[image: Drivers executions times]

One last point to the story is the number of processes and threads. Yes I know I have a 10-year-old CPU, but the premise is that I have even other installations of Windows 10 when this does not happen and the system runs OK. Though there is not much installed and I've only launched in the past to play exclusive Win10 games (or rather games that would not launch on Windows 7).

Moving to that system (which had its problem after upgrading from Windows 8 is a completely different story) and that would equal to be the same as refreshing or just reinstalling completely, which so far I'm trying to avoid.

Here is the last picture, and it's a gadget (yes on Win 10, lol, don't judge) which shows the counts of processes and threads:

[image: Processes, threads & load]

In Windows 7, if I remember correctly, I had about 120 processes idle. On Windows 10 it's about 240-250 and 3500 threads (don't remember a number of threads on Win 7 honestly).

While this all simply could be that Windows 10 is more demanding (has about 100 more processes than Windows 7) and my CPU is simply not able to handle it under the scenarios I'm using my PC. Or it could be something completely different. For example.

Well, here is a report from InSpectre app:

```
Spectre & Meltdown Vulnerability Status
System is Meltdown protected: YES
System is Spectre protected: YES
Microcode Update Available: YES
Performance: SLOWER
CPUID: 306A9
```

This system's present situation:

This 64-bit version of Windows has been updated for full awareness of both the Spectre and the Meltdown vulnerabilities. If the system's hardware (see below) has also been updated, this system will not be vulnerable to these attacks.

This system's hardware has been updated with new features required to allow its operating system to protect against the Spectre vulnerabilities and/or to minimize their impact upon the system's performance. (Protection from the Meltdown vulnerability does not require BIOS or processor updates.)

This system's Intel processor does not provide high-performance protection from the Meltdown vulnerability. The use of Meltdown protection on this system will incur some corresponding performance penalties.

This system's older Intel processor does not provide high-performance protection from the Meltdown vulnerability. Windows is therefore doing the best job it can to protect the system, though with a possibly significant performance penalty. You may wish to consider disabling this system's Meltdown protection until it is offered at a lower system performance cost.

---

So there is a possibility to disable the protection to try to scrape some more performance since I am suspicious of Windows 10 having more inbuilt "stuff" for protection against those flaws than Windows 7 had back then.

I can provide more pictures if needed.

All my life I've been quite "abusing" Windows and calling myself a "power user" and ended up even being QA in my professional career, so I would be very grateful if I could at least uncover what's happening under the hood. I feel the clean install is inevitable (even since I'm planning to buy a new rig), but any help would be greatly appreciated. And sadly there is no easy option to just reinstall all the drivers.

Comment: You need to use the upload the images to the question itself. No one would click such extenal links, and those links may rot in the future which renders the question invalid. Images uploaded to stack.imgur never expires

Comment: @phuclv Thank you for the feedback. Pictures are at imgur now. Not sure however if this shows again in the "feed" since it is already few weeks old.

Comment: no worry, an edit will bump up the question to the top

Comment: "So there is a possibility to disable the protection to try to scrape some more performance since I am suspicious of Windows 10 having more inbuilt "stuff" for protection against those flaws than Windows 7 had back then." - No; Spectre and Meltdown patches are not the sources of your issues. It's been 4 years since they have been a problem. Given the age of your processor, I am pretty sure, your processor isn't even vulnerable to those vulnerabilities.

Comment: The performance hit of those vulnerabilities was computational in nature.  You likely have a third-party application that simply is incompatible with Windows 10.  If you boot into a minimal boot configuration, basically only load your GPU drivers, does this behavior happen?  This means disabling ALL and ANY application that is automatically started.

Comment: I've so far disabled all services besides the ESET anti-malware and AOMEI Backupper and I'm still evaluating. Had trouble to do it first as for some reason, unchecking the "Load system services" in MSConfig would not have any effect and would just revert back.

The system feels already a bit more responsive (even under previously similar load of many threads while having Chrome with lots of tabs & windows).

But it's too soon to judge. Given that these problems occur after longer uptime and also intermittently.

Comment: Is there any other way for a clean boot besides disabling all services and startup items?